# Web service en C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webservice

estoy tratando de hacer un web service pero me da este error en el repositorio con el return y no comprendo porque

El mensaje de error resumiendo dice que como devuelve void, una palabra clave return no debe ir seguida de una expresion de objeto.

```
           public bool PuntoEntrega TarjetahabientePuntoEntregaModificar(TarjetaHabiente tarjetaHabiente, int puntoEntregaID, int idcliente,  DbTransaction transaction)
      {
         var resultado = true;

               try
               {
                   var parametros = new Dictionary<string, object>
                          {
                              { "Nacionalidad", (int)tarjetaHabiente.Nacionalidad },
                              {"Cedula", tarjetaHabiente.Cedula},
                              {"Cliente", tarjetaHabiente.Cliente.ID},
                              {"IDPuntoEntrega", puntoEntregaID},
                              {"IDPuntoEntregaNuevo", tarjetaHabiente.PtoEntrega.ID},
                              {"IDDepartamento", tarjetaHabiente.Departamento.ID}
                          };


                   if (transaction == null)
                   {
                       ExecuteNonQueryFromStoredProcedure("[Operaciones].[TarjetahabientePuntoEntregaModificar]", parametros);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       ExecuteNonQueryFromStoredProcedure("[Operaciones].[TarjetahabientePuntoEntregaModificar]", transaction, parametros);
                   }
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   resultado = false;
                   Notificador.LogError(ErrorTipo.ErrorEnRepositorio, ex, Excepciones.MsjUIErrorGeneral);
               }

               return resultado;
         }
```

Comment: Es muy importante que leas el [tour] y tambien [ask]. No es necesario borrar una pregunta, la podes editar apretando el boton [edit]. Tambien recuerda aceptar las respuestas correctas y completar las preguntas que hiciste si encontraste una solucion.

Comment: El problema e que esta mal escrita la cabecera de la funcion. O devuelve bool o devuelve PuntoEntrega . no puede devolver las dos cosas, salvo que devuelva una tupla...

Comment: Gonzalo, disculpa pero habría alguna forma de que me aclararas algunas dudas? por correo o algo por favor

Comment: Si aceptas las dos respuestas que te dieron, y son correctas. podras entrar al [chat] y ahi podemos ayudarte entre varios

Comment: venga, entrad a la sala, hacemos rituales de iniciación a los nuevos :D hay galletitas :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes definir correctamente la firma de la funcion

```
public bool TarjetahabientePuntoEntregaModificar(TarjetaHabiente tarjetaHabiente, int puntoEntregaID, int idcliente,  DbTransaction transaction)
{
    var resultado = true;

     //resto codigo

    return resultado;
}
```

En este caso elimine `PuntoEntrega` y solo deja el `bool`

Si querias devolver ambos entonces deberias crear uan tercer clase, algo como ser

```
public class Result
{
    public bool success {get;set;}
    public PuntoEntrega data {get;set;}
}
```

entonces la firma seria

```
public Result TarjetahabientePuntoEntregaModificar(...){...
```

De esta forma compones dos valores usando clases

Lo que si veo bastante raro es que definas como parametro un `DbTransaction` de un web service, eso no es correcto.